# Remove 'thanks' footnote from second bibliography when using revtex

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I have two bibliographies in a latex document that's using revtex with the `prb` journal style. I also use the `\thanks{}` command in constructing the title page. Due to the `prb` style, the footnote associated with the thanks is displayed in the bibliography.

However, it shows in both bibliographies and I only want it to show in the first. Can the footnote be removed from the second bibliography?

EDIT: To clarify, I still want to keep the thanks footnote in the first bibliography when removing it from the second bibliography.

A simple example is the following:

```
\documentclass[prb]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\thanks{thanks}
\maketitle

This is a citation \cite{ref1} and this is another \cite{ref2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{36}
\bibitem{ref1} Reference 1.
\end{thebibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{36} 
\bibitem{ref2} Reference 2.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that does what you want, inspired by line `2434` in `revtex4-1.cls`. Not sure if this is legal, I'm new to macros.

```
\documentclass[prb]{revtex4-1}
%\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=10cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\clearfmfn{\let\@FMN@list\@empty}    % <- clears the list of frontmatter footnotes
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\thanks{thanks}
\maketitle

This is a citation \cite{ref1} and this is another \cite{ref2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{36}
\bibitem{ref1} Reference 1.
\end{thebibliography}

\clearfmfn                               % <- call the command after 1st bibliography

\begin{thebibliography}{36}
\bibitem{ref2} Reference 2.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This removes the footnote from both bibliographies. I want to keep it in the first and remove it from the second.

Comment: Alternatively, to move the footnotes to the front page, specify the `nobibnotes` option with the `prb` option for the `revtex4-1` class: `\documentclass[prb,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}`